# How many alleged Islamists does Spain deport or extradite in a year, roughly?

Tags: statistics, spain, extradition, deportation, islamists

[El Pais](https://english.elpais.com/international/2022-05-27/the-algerian-activist-who-may-face-the-death-sentence-after-being-deported-by-spain.html):

> Benhalima requested asylum in Spain, but Spain – which was the first country in the West to show its support for the Algerian regime when the protests broke out – refused his request. The Spanish authorities made this decision on the grounds that he posed “a danger to national security” and could “harm Spain’s relations with other countries.” But the alleged “well-founded” reasons upon which it reached this conclusion have never been explained. [...]
>
> Benhalima is accused of belonging to the Islamist group Rachad, which claims to be peaceful and opposed to the “theocratic” state. But in May 2021, Algerian authorities classified it as a terrorist group. [...]
>
> This is not the first time Spain has tried to please Algeria by returning dissidents. In August 2021, the activist Mohamed Abdellah, a friend of Benhalima’s and former member of Algeria’s Gendarmerie, who became popular on social media for his criticism of corruption within the Gendarmerie, was also handed over. After arriving in Algeria, Abdellah revealed that he had been tortured.

I also found [a 2022 case](https://www.spainenglish.com/2022/11/21/spain-deports-radical-muslim-activist-after-living-in-the-country-for-30-years/) when they deported someone apparently on their own initiative:

> Officers arrested Mohamed Said Badaoui last month in the Catalan province of Tarragona, where he was the president of the Association for the Defence of the Rights of the Muslim Community.
>
> A Spanish court in late October approved his deportation due to ‘his participation in activities contrary to national security’ and ‘public order’.
>
> Spanish police considered Badaoui to be ‘one of the main advocates in Spain of the most orthodox Salafism, which he preaches so influentially that an increase in radicalism occurred in Tarragona’ since he moved there, according to its ruling.
>
> Badaoui arrived in Spain at the age of 10 from Morocco and lived in the Catalan city of Reus for 30 years, where he has a wife and three children.

The merits of specific cases aside, are these events rare though? How many alleged Islamists does Spain deport or extradite in a year, roughly, and not just to Algeria?

(By "alleged" here, assume they've been claimed to be so at least by those requesting their extradition, even if Spain doesn't stamp them as such explicitly. But also include those that Spain agrees they are Islamists and deports them possibly even on their initiative, for that reason.)

Comment: I've tried to answer this, but the thing is Spain tries to keep a low profile of these expulsions, which are quite controversial, and in any case it does not publicity which of those expulsions are islamism-related or due to any other reason (illegal inmigration, mostly). So far I haven't been unable to come with even an estimation of the number.